# inserting multiple objects to arraylist

Tags: java, oop, object, arraylist

i want the user to enter the appointment variables which is (name , doctor name , section , day , time) and store it in an object , then add it to the ArrayList. and it should be able to add another appointment. until the user decide not to book an appointment. tell me what is the missing peace in my code ?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input =new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Object> appointments = new ArrayList<>();
    appointment xx = new appointment();

    System.out.println("do you want to book an appointment? (0/yes , 1/no) ");
    int ch = input.nextInt();

    while (ch==0){
    System.out.println("** Book appointment **");
    System.out.println("* to book an appointment choose a doctor, section, time and day from below :");
    System.out.println("Doctors : Dr.ahmed , Dr.sara , Dr.ali , Dr.maha ");
    System.out.println("Sections : Skin , Dental "); 
    System.out.println("Times : from 8AM to 4PM");
    System.out.println("Days : from Sunday to Thursday");
    System.out.println("          ");

    System.out.println("please enter your name :");
    String a1 = input.nextLine();
    xx.setPatient(a1);

    System.out.println("please enter the doctor name : ");
    String a2 = input.nextLine();
    xx.setDoctor(a2);

    System.out.println("please enter the section : ");
    String a3 = input.nextLine();
    xx.setSection(a3);

    System.out.println("please enter the time : ");
    String a4 = input.nextLine();
    xx.setTime(a4);

    System.out.println("please enter the day : ");
    String a5 = input.nextLine();
    xx.setDay(a5);

    appointments.add(xx);
    System.out.println(appointments);

    System.out.println("do you want to book another appointment? (0/yes , 1/no) ");
    ch = input.nextInt();
 }
```

}

}

```
 class appointment {
    public String Day;
    public String Time;
    public String Doctor;
    public String Section;
    public String Patient;
    public static int numberOfApp;



    public appointment(){

 }


    public appointment(String Day, String Time, String Doctor, String Section, String Patient) {
        this.Day = Day;
        this.Time = Time;
        this.Doctor = Doctor;
        this.Section = Section;
        this.Patient = Patient;
    }

    public static void setNumberOfApp(int numberOfApp) {
    appointment.numberOfApp = numberOfApp;
    }

    public void setDay(String Day) {
        this.Day = Day;
    }

    public void setTime(String Time) {
        this.Time = Time;
    }

    public void setDoctor(String Doctor) {
        this.Doctor = Doctor;
    }

    public void setSection(String Section) {
        this.Section = Section;
    }

    public void setPatient(String Patient) {
        this.Patient = Patient;
    }

    public static int getNumberOfApp() {
    return numberOfApp;
    }

    public String getDay() {
        return Day;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return Time;
    }

    public String getDoctor() {
        return Doctor;
    }

    public String getSection() {
        return Section;
    }

    public String getPatient() {
        return Patient;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return " ";
    }

    public void add_appointment (){

    }

 }
```

Comment: You only ever create one appointment object which you keep adding a reference to the list.  Using your debugger, you should be able to see what you need to do is create one appointment object for each appointment you want to add.

Answer (score 1):

Class names should start with an upper case character

```
appointment xx = new appointment();
```

You only ever create a single `Appointment` object. You can't reuse it just because you add it to the ArrayList.

You need to create the `Appointment` object inside your while loop so you have a different object for each appointment.